# What is the easiest way to tell what resources a settler is assigned to in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

My Sanctuary Hills settlement in Fallout 4 has 14 settlers and I'm struggling to tell what resources each of them are assigned to - or if they're assigned to any resource at all.

Currently the only way I know to see assigned resources is by hovering over a settler in workshop mode their assigned resources will highlight in green.

This works okay if they are standing near their resource - but as my settlement has grown in physical size/ complexity/ population it's become harder and harder to use this method.

Is there another way to see which settlers are assigned to which resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no overview of what all of your settlers are doing. The only current method to see what a settler is assigned to is as mentioned in your question.

See also: [Can I see an overview of my settlers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242793/52800)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer in the comment, hovering over settlers will highlight the resources they are assigned to.

Additionally, if you hover over a resource, you can check the information window. If the settler symbol in it is red and not green, there is no worker assigned to it and therefore, it won't do anything.

Comment: Side note: The icon is not necessarily green. It is *ok/good* when it is displayed in whatever you have set as your GUI color and it's *not ok/bad* when it is displayed red. TBH I have no clue what happens if you happen to set your GUI color to red - will check tonight...

Comment: Well, I can expand the answer to "if you set the gui color to green, then its green, when you set it to  blue, its blue" and so on, but that doesn't seem necessary to me. :P

Comment: 'course not, thats why it's just a comment and not an edit ;-) Still curious about what happens if you set it to red though - You wouldn't be able to tell then, which might throw off some folks.